Vscode vim remaping g_ to $ not working, how to fix this?
So whenever I try to select till the end of the line with v$ the cursor is moved to the start of the next line so if I do d for delete then the content from the next line is brought up, this is very annoying.
I tried
  "vim.visualModeKeyBindings": [
    {
      "before": ["g", "_"],
      "after": ["$"]
    }
  ],

but it's not picking this up the cursor still goes to the next line whenever I do v$
I tried using a .vimrc changes from this is not working either.
I'm finding this very annoying because JetBrains with vimidea $ and vim itself only goes till the end of the line and I'm used to it.
